# Q.Promise array, alert if more than 1 fulfilled

Tags: javascript, promise, q, deferred

I'm using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library for handling promises.
Lets say I have an array of promises, which I'm waiting for the first one to be fulfilled in order to return its value.

I'm expecting only one of the promises to be fulfilled, yet I cannot guarantee this situation and therefore I'd like to do SOMETHING if another promise has been fulfilled after the first one.

Obviously I could use Q.allSettled but then I'd have to wait for all the promises to be fulfilled/rejected before I could access the value of the first fulfilled promise.

I was wondering if there's a way of accessing the value of the first promise to be returned while still handle the other promises, so I can alert if another promise if fulfilled.

Hope my question is clear, thanks for your help.

### Edit1 - code snippet

As you can see, this code returns the value of the first fulfilled promise.
I want to keep this behaviour while still being able to take action if a second promise is fulfilled.

```
var getDataSourcePromise = function(table, profileId) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    table.retrieveEntity(tableName, profileId, profileId, function(err, result, response) {
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(Error(err));
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

var promises = [];
tables.forEach(function(table, profileId) {
    promises.push(getDataSourcePromise(table, profileId.toString()));
});

console.log('waiting for settle');

Q.any(promises).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

### Edit2 - more information

Given you understand what the above code should do, I have a generalized `GetDataSource(profileId): Q.Promise<DataSource>` function (`input: profileId`, `output: a promise for a DataSource`).

I need to return the value of the first fulfilled promise to whomever called me, as soon as it was fulfilled --- meaning I need to return `Q.any(promises)`.
On the other hand, I still need to execute this part of code (Benjamin Gruenbaum's):

```
Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(result){
    if(result.filter(function(p){ return p.state === "fulfilled"; })){
       alert("Sanity failure"); // do whatever you need to recover
    }
});
```

What do you recommend I do? (sorry for not being clear enough before)

Comment: Could you post a sample code snippet to demonstrate your situation to let us understand your question easier?

Comment: added code snippet as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fork promises and create multiple branches:

```
var promises = tables.map(function(table) { 
    return getDataSourcePromise(table, profileId.toString());
});

Q.any(promises).then(function(result){
   console.log("Result", result); // processing done
});
Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(result){
    if(result.filter(function(p){ return p.state === "fulfilled"; })){
       alert("Sanity failure"); // do whatever you need to recover
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, clearly I did not supply information and I'm sorry for that, could you please read Edit2 ?
Your answer helped me understand something else though..

Comment: @johni I don't understand, my solution still works after the edit, just `return` the `Q.any` and put the `allSettled` above it?

Comment: In this way, the `.then` of the `Q.allSettled` will be executed after the `Q.any` was returned to the caller and the program kept on its flow?

Comment: Johni, you said you want "to do something if *another* promise has been fulfilled after the first one". Does the sanity alert here not happen for "all" successful responses, including the first?